# Crashing during transition cocos2d

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I'm using cocos2d to create an app. I'm using the swipe gesture the below code to trigger an transition:

```
-(void) handleSwipeLeft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer  {
    CCLOG(@"Swiped Left");
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionPageTurn transitionWithDuration:1 scene:[Page1 scene]]];
    [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine]unloadEffect:@"Page 1.mp3"];
}
```

My problem is that if the user swipes left twice (perhaps they're very enthusiastic about changing scenes), the app will crash. I'm not a professional coder, but it seems like the `transitionWithDuration` is allowing additional touches to call other methods and do other stuff before dealloc is called. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

My full code is:

```
#import "Page1.h"
#import "Page2.h"
#import "OptionsMenu.h"
#import "MainMenu.h"

//activate music

#import "SimpleAudioEngine.h"
#import "CDAudioManager.h"

@implementation Page1

+(CCScene *) scene
{
    // 'scene' is an autorelease object.
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

    // 'layer' is an autorelease object.
    Page1 *layer = [Page1 node];

    // add layer as a child to scene
    [scene addChild: layer];

    // return the scene
    return scene;
}

-(id) init
{
    // always call "super" init
    // Apple recommends to re-assign "self" with the "super's" return value
    if( (self=[super init]) ) {

        CCLOG(@"Entering the Page 1 init method");

        //getting the screen dimensions
        CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

        //adding the background
        CCSprite *menuBackground = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Page 1.png"];

        menuBackground.position = ccp(size.width/2,size.height/2);
        [self addChild:menuBackground];

        //pause button
        CCMenuItemImage *pause = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage: @"optionsButton.png" selectedImage: @"optionsButton.png" target:self selector:@selector(openMenu)];

        CCMenu *pauseButton = [CCMenu menuWithItems:pause, nil];
        [self addChild:pauseButton];
        pauseButton.position = ccp(40,30);
        pauseButton.scale = 1;

        //page label
        CCLabelTTF *label = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Page 1" fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:24];
        label.position = ccp(500,20);
        [self addChild:label];

        //using menus as the text label
        CCLabelTTF *one = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"I" fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:24];
        CCLabelTTF *two = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"see" fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:24];
        CCLabelTTF *three = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"that" fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:24];
        CCLabelTTF *four = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"I" fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:24];
        CCLabelTTF *five = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"hold" fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:24];
        CCLabelTTF *six = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"a" fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:24];
        CCLabelTTF *seven = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"sanctuary" fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:24];
        CCLabelTTF *eight = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"in" fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:24];
        CCLabelTTF *nine = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"their" fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:24];
        CCLabelTTF *ten = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"hearts" fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:24];

        CCMenuItemLabel *w1 = [CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel:one target:self selector:@selector(w1)];
        CCMenuItemLabel *w2 = [CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel:two target:self selector:@selector(w2)];
        CCMenuItemLabel *w3 = [CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel:three target:self selector:@selector(w3)];
        CCMenuItemLabel *w4 = [CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel:four target:self selector:@selector(w4)];
        CCMenuItemLabel *w5 = [CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel:five target:self selector:@selector(w5)];
        CCMenuItemLabel *w6 = [CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel:six target:self selector:@selector(w6)];
        CCMenuItemLabel *w7 = [CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel:seven target:self selector:@selector(w7)];
        CCMenuItemLabel *w8 = [CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel:eight target:self selector:@selector(w8)];
        CCMenuItemLabel *w9 = [CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel:nine target:self selector:@selector(w9)];
        CCMenuItemLabel *w10 = [CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel:ten target:self selector:@selector(w10)];

        //upper line
        CCMenu *textMenu1 = [CCMenu menuWithItems:w1,w2,w3,w4,w5,w6,w7, nil];
        [self addChild:textMenu1];
        textMenu1.position = ccp(size.width/2,64);
        [textMenu1 alignItemsHorizontallyWithPadding:7];

        //bottom line
        CCMenu *textMenu2 = [CCMenu menuWithItems:w8,w9,w10, nil];
        [self addChild:textMenu2];
        textMenu2.position = ccp(size.width/2,40);
        [textMenu2 alignItemsHorizontallyWithPadding:7];

        //play music
        [SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine].effectsVolume = 1;

        [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine]playEffect:@"Page 1.mp3"];

        //enabling swipe gestures            
        [self addSwipeGestures];   
    }
    return self;
}

//definiing swipe gesture parameters    
#pragma mark Add UISwipeGestureRecognizer and Handlers

-(void) addSwipeGestures {

    swipeUp =[[ UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action:@selector( handleSwipeUp:)]; // colon after method
    swipeUp.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
    [ [ [CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addGestureRecognizer: swipeUp]; //  add swipe up
    [swipeUp release];

    swipeDownGR =[[ UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action:@selector( handleSwipeDown:)]; // colon after method
    swipeDownGR.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;
    [ [ [CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addGestureRecognizer: swipeDownGR]; //  add swipe down
    [swipeDownGR release];

    swipeLeft =[[ UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action:@selector( handleSwipeLeft:)]; // colon after method
    swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    [ [ [CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addGestureRecognizer: swipeLeft]; //  add swipe left
    [swipeLeft release];

    swipeRight =[[ UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action:@selector( handleSwipeRight:)]; // colon after method
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    [ [ [CCDirector sharedDirector] view]  addGestureRecognizer: swipeRight]; //  add swipe right
    [swipeRight release];        
}

//adding swipe gesture functions    
-(void) handleSwipeUp:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer  {
    CCLOG(@"Swiped Up");
}

-(void) handleSwipeDown:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer  {
    CCLOG(@"Swiped Down");  
}

-(void) handleSwipeLeft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer  {
    CCLOG(@"Swiped Left");
    //[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[Page2 scene]];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionPageTurn transitionWithDuration:1 scene:[Page1 scene]]];
    [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine]unloadEffect:@"Page 1.mp3"];
}

-(void) handleSwipeRight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer  {
    CCLOG(@"Swiped Right");
}

-(void)openMenu
{
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pushScene:[OptionsMenu scene]];
    [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine]unloadEffect:@"Page 1.mp3"];
}

//methods for the text menus    
-(void)w1 {

}

-(void)w2 {

}

-(void)w3 {

}

-(void)w4 {

}

-(void)w5 {

}

-(void)w6 {

}

-(void)w7 {

}

-(void)w8 {

}

-(void)w9 {

}

-(void)w10 {

}

-(void) dealloc {
    CCLOG( @"removing Page 1 instance" );
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: What's the actual error message / crash behavior? We need to know what we're dealing with here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the gesture recognizers. If they stay around, the next time you do a swipe it will be invalid. For example add the following:

```
-(void) onExit
{
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] removeGestureRecognizer:swipeUp];
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] removeGestureRecognizer:swipeDownGR];
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] removeGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] removeGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];

    [super onExit];
}
```

Comment: You can also remove them before doing the transition to be safe.

Answer (score -1):

> I'm not a professional coder, but it seems [...] dealloc [...]. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

What you're doing wrong is trying to program without enabling ARC. Everybody should enable ARC, especially less experienced developers who want to avoid bugs like this one.

Turn ARC on for your project, it will give you a bunch of compile errors (for example, you are not allowed to call `[super dealloc]` with ARC enabled, it will tell you to delete that line of code), and then your bug will almost certainly vanish.

If you run into something that can't be done with ARC, you can disable it on a per-file basis, so there's no reason not to enable ARC for the project. Chances are you'll never need to turn ARC off.

These days the only reason to avoid ARC is if you want to support really old hardware. But it's so old now it probably doesn't exist in the wild (batteries would have failed, etc.).